# Photon Player change scenes

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

i make a multiplayer game with photon.

i have 3 scenes (main scene,Level1,Level2)

i instantiate my player in main scene and i want to go on trigger to other scene(level 1 ) with my player and come back again from level1 to main screen with the same player..

Can someone help me im stuck for days..

Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

You should tell wich photon version you use (pun , fusion).
As far as I know, the scene change is performed by either the host or server, over the networkrunner.

For exemple, in photon Fusion a simple "_runner.SetActiveScene(scene_int);" in the host or server is enough, with a don't destroy on load on the player

Here is the photon fusion answer by documentation just in case you didn't saw it https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/fusion/current/manual/scene-loading

I also suggest you use the game loop example provided here : https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/fusion/current/technical-samples/fusion-application-loop#scenes

Comment: For exemple, in photon Fusion a simple "_runner.SetActiveScene(scene_int);" in the host or server is enough, with a don't destroy on load on the player